# "Refresh Property Sheet" has encountered

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

An internal error has occurred.
java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: What's that error]

Always appear when i am saving my class or open Manifest file.

Comment: This drove me crazy! It'd appear every 10 seconds.

Comment: Cleaning, closing and restarting stops the problem for a while, but then it comes back. What causes this in the first place, and how can I avoid creating this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Project >> Clean >> Clean the project. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Cleaning, closing and restarting stops the problem for a while, but then it comes back. What causes this in the first place, and how can I avoid creating this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i've got this exception .

when i open the manifest.xml file, after clean the project, i get the same exception..

finally i cleaned the project and closed all files and restarted the eclipse .

There after only the problem solved.